# Connection refused - connect(2) httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im getting this error "Connection refused - connect(2)" while sending a post through HttParty with the thin server, in heroku i get the same error. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an authentication issue. Check your username and password combination or whatever else you show before connection. Also check to see that that user has rights to post.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your use of http vs https. In my case, I was using an incorrect url. I should have been using http://api.mashery.com but was using https://api.mashery.com